# Combinate data in one array

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, left-join

Can you tell me guys what i missing ? how can i put all data in one array ?
the query atm look like this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT
                        oc_fast_order_option.*,
                        oc_product_description.name AS product_name,
                        oc_fast_order.quantity
                        FROM oc_fast_order_option
                        LEFT JOIN oc_fast_order ON (oc_fast_order.id = '" . $order_id . "')
                        LEFT JOIN oc_product_description ON (oc_product_description.product_id = oc_fast_order.product_id)
                        WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");

    return $query->rows;
```

result from this query is separate in few arrays and when i loop i cant display result properly

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_option_id] => 56
        [order_id] => 118
        [order_product_id] => 52
        [product_option_id] => 745
        [product_option_value_id] => 1104
        [name] => Цветове:
        [value] => Черен
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_option_id] => 55
        [order_id] => 118
        [order_product_id] => 52
        [product_option_id] => 746
        [product_option_value_id] => 0
        [name] => new input
        [value] => 3
    )
)
```

how can i get something like  this ?

```
 Array
  (
    [option_id] = >
     Array(
    [order_option_id] => 56
    [order_option_id] => 55
     )

    [order_id] => 118
    [order_product_id] => 52
    [product_option_id] => 745
    [product_option_value_id] => 1104
    [options] = > 
    Array(
    [name] => Цветове:
    [value] => Черен
     )
)
```

what i tried to do is loop them and put into one array

```
foreach ($query->rows as $data) {
                    $data['info_options'][] = array(
                        'options'       => array(
                        'option_name'           => $data['name'],
                        'value_name'            => $data['value']
                        ),
                        'quantity'  => $data['quantity'],
                        'product_link'  => HTTP_CATALOG.'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' . $product_id,
                        'product_name'  => $data['product_name']
                    );
                }
```

but result is still not grate

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [options] => Array
            (
                [option_name] => Цветове:
                [value_name] => Черен
            )

        [quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => aapp
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [options] => Array
            (
                [option_name] => new input
                [value_name] => 3
            )

        [quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => aapp
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [options] => Array
            (
                [option_name] => Custom-Input
                [value_name] => 5
            )

        [quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => aapp
    )

)
```

**UPDATE**
finally i get what i needed

```
Array
(
[op] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Цветове:
                [value] => Черен
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => new input
                [value] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Custom
                [value] => 5
            )

    )

[name] => aapp
[quantity] => 1
)
```

what i did is 2 querys one for options and one for rest info
then i loop option query and put result in one array then loop second query and put in new array where i add and option array

Comment: That's not a common format - you have to write some code to achieve that

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Just what I've said: the expected format is not that common to be achieved with the built-in features of PHP. A database query will always return full rows instead of that mixed form you expect - but writing some code to transform the array should no be too hard. Give it a try and attach your attempt to the question if you face any issues with that

Comment: i did something but still not getting what i want  i update question

Comment: Well, that's obvious: in the given row, you create a new sub-array in each iteration. You should somehow keep track of the last element by some of the unique keys you've defined, and fill up an existing sub-array if one is found

Comment: any example how that can be done ?

Comment: That depends on the rules in your system, which you haven't added to the question. Have a try and share that if something does not work

Comment: @Nico Haase thanks i did it